# Salesforce SOQL Filter by child relationship

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have the following simple query which shows I can access the field I want to filter by:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT HC4__IsSearchableExternally__c FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
```

However, what I really want to do is return only the Id and Name properties for Accounts that have at least one Contact where `HC4__IsSearchableExternally__c` is true. Is this possible to do with a Salesforce query?

Basically, I want to do something like the following (nonfunctional query):

```sql
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Contacts WHERE HC4__IsSearchableExternally__c = true) > 0
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a semi-join, e.g:

```sql
select id, name from account 
where id in (select accountId from contact where HC4__IsSearchableExternally__c = true)
```

Comment: Can we query parent record( say, Account) based on 2 filter criteria based on 2 child objects (say, Contact and another object-Test)?